# WinUsb_Initialize always get 0 and error 31

Tags: python, ctypes, windows-api-code-pack

I use python and refer to the following website to modify the code
https://github.com/thesacredmoocow/g14control-r2/blob/cc8064b38dbddca551f0301a254b578c508122f5/winusbpy/examples/winusbtest2.py

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceinterfacedetaila

```
import time
from winusbpy import *
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *


DIGCF_DEFAULT = 0x00000001
DIGCF_PRESENT = 0x00000002
DIGCF_ALLCLASSES = 0x00000004
DIGCF_PROFILE = 0x00000008
DIGCF_DEVICE_INTERFACE = 0x00000010


GENERIC_WRITE = (1073741824)
GENERIC_READ = (-2147483648)
FILE_SHARE_READ = 1
FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 2
OPEN_EXISTING = 3
OPEN_ALWAYS = 4
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 128
FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED = 1073741824

INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = HANDLE(-1)

PIPE_TYPE_CONTROL = 0
PIPE_TYPE_ISO = 1
PIPE_TYPE_BULK = 2
PIPE_TYPE_INTERRUPT = 3

ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE = 996
ERROR_IO_PENDING = 997

vid = "1234"
pid = "5678"
path = ""
interface_descriptor = UsbInterfaceDescriptor()

api = WinUSBApi()
byte_array = c_byte * 8
guid = GUID(0xA5DCBF10, 0x6530, 0x11D2, byte_array(0x90, 0x1F, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x4F, 0xB9, 0x51, 0xED))
flags = DWORD(DIGCF_DEVICE_INTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT)
i = 0
member_index = DWORD(i)
required_size = c_ulong(0)

sp_device_info_data = SpDevinfoData()
sp_device_interface_data = SpDeviceInterfaceData()
sp_device_interface_detail_data = SpDeviceInterfaceDetailData()

sp_device_interface_data.cb_size = sizeof(sp_device_interface_data)
sp_device_info_data.cb_size = sizeof(sp_device_info_data)

hdev_info = api.exec_function_setupapi("SetupDiGetClassDevs", byref(guid), None, None, flags)


while api.exec_function_setupapi("SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces", hdev_info, None, byref(guid), member_index,
                                 byref(sp_device_interface_data)):
    
    
    api.exec_function_setupapi("SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail", hdev_info, byref(sp_device_interface_data), None, 0,
                               byref(required_size), None)
    resize(sp_device_interface_detail_data, required_size.value)
    
    sp_device_interface_detail_data.cb_size = sizeof(SpDeviceInterfaceDetailData) - sizeof(WCHAR * 1)

    if api.exec_function_setupapi("SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail", hdev_info, byref(sp_device_interface_data),
                                  byref(sp_device_interface_detail_data), required_size, byref(required_size),
                                  byref(sp_device_info_data)):
        path = wstring_at(byref(sp_device_interface_detail_data, sizeof(DWORD)))
        print(path)
        if is_device(vid, pid, path):
            print("PATH: " + path)
            break
    else:
        error_code = api.exec_function_kernel32("GetLastError")
        print("Error: " + str(error_code))

    i += 1
    member_index = DWORD(i)
    required_size = c_ulong(0)
    resize(sp_device_interface_detail_data, sizeof(SpDeviceInterfaceDetailData))


handle_file = api.exec_function_kernel32("CreateFileW", path, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
                                         FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ, None, OPEN_EXISTING,
                                         FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, None)

if INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == handle_file:
    print("Error Creating File")
else:
    print("No error")
    handle_winusb = c_void_p()
    result = api.exec_function_winusb("WinUsb_Initialize", handle_file, byref(handle_winusb))
    print(result)

    if result != 0:

        info_type = c_ulong(1)
        buff = (c_void_p * 1)()
        buff_length = c_ulong(sizeof(c_void_p))

        result = api.exec_function_winusb("WinUsb_QueryDeviceInformation", handle_winusb, info_type, byref(buff_length),
                                          buff)
        if result != 0:
            print("Speed: " + str(buff[0]))

        else:
            error_code = api.exec_function_kernel32("GetLastError")
            print("Error Query Device: " + str(error_code))

        """ Interface Settings """
        response = api.exec_function_winusb("WinUsb_QueryInterfaceSettings", handle_winusb, c_ubyte(0),
                                            byref(interface_descriptor))

        if response == 0:
            error_code = api.exec_function_kernel32("GetLastError")
            print("Error Query Interface: " + str(error_code))
        if response != 0:
            print("bLength: " + str(interface_descriptor.b_length))
            print("bDescriptorType: " + str(interface_descriptor.b_descriptor_type))
            print("bInterfaceNumber: " + str(interface_descriptor.b_interface_number))
            print("bAlternateSetting: " + str(interface_descriptor.b_alternate_setting))
            print("bNumEndpoints " + str(interface_descriptor.b_num_endpoints))
            print("bInterfaceClass " + str(interface_descriptor.b_interface_class))
            print("bInterfaceSubClass: " + str(interface_descriptor.b_interface_sub_class))
            print("bInterfaceProtocol: " + str(interface_descriptor.b_interface_protocol))
            print("iInterface: " + str(interface_descriptor.i_interface))

            """ Endpoints information """
            i = 0
            endpoint_index = c_ubyte(0)
            pipe_info = PipeInfo()
            while i <= interface_descriptor.b_num_endpoints:
                result = api.exec_function_winusb("WinUsb_QueryPipe", handle_winusb, c_ubyte(0), endpoint_index,
                                                  byref(pipe_info))
                if result != 0:
                    print("PipeType: " + str(pipe_info.pipe_type))
                    print("PipeId: " + str(pipe_info.pipe_id))
                    print("MaximumPacketSize: " + str(pipe_info.maximum_packet_size))
                    print("Interval: " + str(pipe_info.interval))
                i += 1
                endpoint_index = c_ubyte(i)

          

    else:
        error_code = api.exec_function_kernel32("GetLastError")
        print("Error" + str(error_code))
```

but I print this code always get 0 result and get error 31 What did i do wrong

```
result = api.exec_function_winusb("WinUsb_Initialize", handle_file, byref(handle_winusb))
```

**update**

```
DIGCF_DEFAULT = 0x00000001
DIGCF_PRESENT = 0x00000002
DIGCF_ALLCLASSES = 0x00000004
DIGCF_PROFILE = 0x00000008
DIGCF_DEVICE_INTERFACE = 0x00000010


GENERIC_WRITE = 0x80000000
GENERIC_READ = 0x40000000
FILE_SHARE_READ = 1
FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 2
OPEN_EXISTING = 3
OPEN_ALWAYS = 4
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 0x00000080
FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED = 0x40000000
```

Comment: `result = api.exec_function_winusb("WinUsb_Initialize", handle_file, handle_winusb)`?

Comment: still get error 31 ....

Comment: Does the device work in other circumstances? Post the exact output of the above code. Why is *GENERIC\_READ* negative? Also the package seems to be outdated (and buggy).

Comment: did not execute successfully,GENERIC_READ Fixed to 0x40000000 ,but still get error 31

Comment: I changed the question you mentioned, Error becomes 6